# Panels side by side taking up 50% width each

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two panels: panelA, panelB in a panel: panelContainer.

How do I make panelA and panelB go side by side taking 50% width each of the panelContainer?

Comment: tha parent panel has a fixed width? assign to each panel the parent with / 2... could you bring us more detail please.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) with one row(100%) and two columns (50% each).

Answer (score 22):

You can use `SplitContainer` instead of panel. Set `IsSplitterFixed` to **true**, in design mode set `SplitterDistance` to be half of `SplitContainer`'s width and set the `SplitterWidth` to **1**. Make sure that `FixedPanel` is set to **none**. Then at runtime it will maintain the ratio of panels widths.

The only problem is that you can't set `SplitterWidth` to zero so there will always be a slight distance between panels. If that's not a problem and if you don't need the `panelContainer` to actually be a panel for some reason, that's the way I would do it.

Comment: `in design mode set SplitPosition to be half of SplitContainer's width` there is no such thing as a `SplitPosition`... What do you mean by that?

Comment: @sLw it should be `SplitterDistance`

Comment: One thing to note here: Clicking on the control will always select one panel or the other, not the control itself. To access the control's properties, right mouse click on the control (either panel) and select the name of the control. The properties in the properties explorer will then reflect the properties of the control, not those of one panel or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Check SplitterDistance Property. Override form resize and set this value = form.width / 2;

See more.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.splitterdistance?view=netframework-4.8