# Two RichTextBox C#, alignment in to middle of screen

Tags: c#, alignment, richtextbox

I'm creating windows form app in C#, and I have 2 richTextBoxes.

How can I set it to half of screen ->  when I change size of Form, richBoxes will be allways on half of screen

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: [C# Winforms panels side by side taking up 50% width each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098812/c-sharp-winforms-panels-side-by-side-taking-up-50-width-each)

Use a SplitContainer. Set IsSplitterFixed to true, in design mode set SplitPosition to be half of SplitContainer's width and set the SplitterWidth to 1. Make sure that FixedPanel is set to none. Then at runtime it will maintain the ratio of panels widths.